# Can't find Windows Subsystem for Linux in Control Panel

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 32-bit

I'm trying to install Windows Subsystem for Linux but I can't find it in my control panel. I tried to search on this Super User site and some more sites they said that I need to enable the Developer Mode. I enabled it but still I can't find that feature. I tried to use the PowerShell method. But when I executed then command it failed:

[image]

Anyone can help me? This is the info of the Windows I'm using:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see your specs, you are however, using Windows 10 32-bit on 64-bit processor.

[Check configuration](https://www.howto-connect.com/install-linux-subsystem-windows-10/) - For the features of Linux to run on a given system, it requires a 64-bit version of Windows 10.

I don't think this is possible with 32-bit Windows.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. WSL is not available in 32bit Windows 10. [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#check-your-build-number) is the official link.